# Date filter in sql query to get today value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want a link from data table where logo link is <= fromdate and >= todate.

I' writing this query to get value

```
select *  from getlogo 

select * from getlogo 
where (Convert(date,logofrom) >= getdate()) and (Convert(date,logoto) <= getdate()) 
and active=0


 today = 03/25/2015
 from = database.value logofrom 
 to = database.value logoto     
 how to compare this and get value
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logo that has a date range in which today falls then reverse the conditions:

```
(Convert(date,logofrom) <= getdate()) and (Convert(date,logoto) >= getdate())
```

This would return the logo with `id = 2` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You should CAST GetDate in order to include dates on edges:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    getlogo
WHERE   CAST(logofrom AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        AND CAST(logoto AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        AND active = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If by your description, you need the second record as result..

use this query

```
select * from getlogo where getdate() between convert(datetime,logofrom) 
and convert(datetime,logoto) and  active=0
```